# Upload multiple document with requierd field

Tags: sharepoint-server

my problem is , when I want to upload a multiple document, i want to attribute the same value for some field , department, date, those field is required, is there any way to do it .

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the default value for the fields you wish to be the same just prior to uploading multiple documents and then manually reset the default value for those fields afterwards.

Or, consider [bulk updating the metadata using datasheet view](http://sharepointquester.com/2012/10/12/using-the-datasheet-view-to-bulk-update-sharepoint-2010-list-columns/) or [programmatically via PowerShell](http://jespermchristensen.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/bulk-change-list-item-metadata-in-sharepoint-2010/).

Comment: can you give more details for the second solution, or some useful link.
thanks,

Comment: @Aissam I updated my answer with a couple of links. Hope that helps!

Comment: Good, but an admin SHP must run the script, is there any way for the user do it for is his self ?, the datasheet view must browse file by file, if there's 100 files..., it's become difficult.

Comment: @Aissam You are correct, a script would need to be run by an administrator, not an end user. If the "default value" and datasheet view options are not workable for you, try to find a 3rd party solution (or develop one). There are several on codeplex and likely many for sale also. Just found this solution for instance though I haven't used it: https://store.qipoint.com/product-p/sp14-01-batch.htm --hopefully I have pointed you in a helpful direction!